# How can I deploy a server container to ECS Fargate?

Tags: docker, express, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

It is a simple express.js API that listens for http requests on port 80

Before building the image and pushing it to DockerHub I created an endpoint for the "check health status":

```
app.get("/health", (_, res: Response) => res.sendStatus(200));

const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT;

app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}. `);
});
```

I checked this path on my local machine and it seems to be working:
[Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYXNZ.png)

I deployed it to AWS ECS Fargate: Created the cluster, created the task definition following the instructions that I used in the docker-compose.yaml file, created a service based on the task definition I created and launched that service. At the AWS console everything seems to working fine too:
[Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeHJd.png)

So I tried sending a HTTP request to the DNS name of the Load balancer /health, and also to the IP/port address /health, but the requests all timeout:
[Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsNBI.png)

Comment: What are the security group settings for the security group assigned to the load balancer? And the security group assigned to the ECS task?

Comment: @MarkB It was indeed an inbound rule at a security group. You are very humble and very kind, sir. Thank you so much for being so awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with an inbound rule at a security group, as our friend Mark B suggested in the comments